# While I was trying an example, MySQL RANGE PARTITION not displaying values properly in specified partitions. My Complete details as follows

Tags: mysql, sql, database-partitioning

I've created a table with range partition as

```
 CREATE TABLE nums_range (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
 )   PARTITION BY RANGE(id) (
     PARTITION p0mil VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
     PARTITION p1mil VALUES LESS THAN (2000000),
     PARTITION p2mil VALUES LESS THAN (3000000),
     PARTITION p3mil VALUES LESS THAN (4000000),
     PARTITION p4mil VALUES LESS THAN (5000000)
 );
```

And I've Inserted following values

```
 INSERT INTO nums_range (id) VALUES 
 (900000),(1),(1500050),(1699876),(2700000),(3000000),(3500000),(4000000),(4500000);
```

So when I type the following query

```
 SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'nums_range';
```

I get a table showing how partitions has been done...and that's nice. To view the table [Click Here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-4TErxMfBLSU/VDQBEU9fTmI/AAAAAAAAALI/j1FN7DKcAOo/s576/pic2.jpg). You might have observed from the figure that Partition p2mil has one row of data and others are having 2 rows each. When I drop the first partition i.e. p0mil, then the data belongs to that partition gets deleted. But the problem is when I select remaining partitions, Partitions p2mil shows 0 row though It actually has its row. Why???
[Click Here](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EVulS9PSSgY/VDQBEUEaj4I/AAAAAAAAALE/PWjBYyAKeyU/s512/pic3.jpg) to see commands with output for better understanding my problem.

Please Help me Since I'm new to MySQL Partitioning.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because MySQL does not automatically update the stats of the existing partitions. You need to analyze the remaining partitions again,
    alter table nums_range analyze PARTITION p1mil;
    alter table nums_range analyze PARTITION p2mil;
    alter table nums_range analyze PARTITION p3mil;

After running the above commands, rerun your query to check, you should only see 7 records in the table

Comment: Hi Paladin
Can you help me solving this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858171/getting-unexpected-result-with-range-partitioning-in-mysql
related to partitioning